# Anaconda: Install specific packages from specific channels using environment.yml

Tags: python, dependencies, anaconda, environment

does anyone know how to construct an Anaconda environment.yml file so that it installs specific packages from specific channels?

Something like this:

```
dependencies:
  - numpy
  - pandas
  - package-A from channel Z
  - package-B from channel Y
```

All I could find is that you can specify channels using the **channels:** command. But apparently it then grabs the packages from the first channel its available on - but I need some packages from very specific channels (but it exists on multiple ones in different "versions").

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I saw something like

```
dependencies:
- chanelname::modulename=X.Y.Z
```

**Update**
It now implemented:
https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7202

**Old answer**
Be carefull since [it doesn't seemed to be implemented](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/2800). A channel is, by design, a "space" where depencies are robust. So removing this might break dependencies.

Comment: This syntax is now supported (https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7202)

Comment: This doesn't seem to accept "defaults" as a channel, ie. `defaults::foo`.